# The complex derivative of $f \overline{f}$.

Tags: complex-analysis

Consider a holomorphic function $f$, and consider a function $g(z,w)= f(z) \overline{f(w)}$, I want to consider the following limit question:
$lim_{h\to 0}\frac{g(z+h,z+h)-g(z,z+h)+g(z,z)-g(z+h,z)}{|h|^2}$. Does this limit exist? How to compute it?

Thoughts: I want to get a taste of it by first taking $f = z$, and try to compute it. Then I need to compute the following: $lim_{h \to 0} \frac{|z+h|^2-z\bar h-|z|^2-h\bar z}{|h|^2}$. My guess is that it should be equal to 1, since if I look at the case where all things are real, then it is one of if I just make $z$ equal zero, then it is also 1.

Then my guess is the limit should probably be of the form $f'(z) \overline{f'(z)}$.

Plus, I know that if $g$ is just a real $C^2$ function, the limit should give me $g_{xy}$, but how to deal with it in the complex case, maybe essentially the same trick?

Comment: Suggestion: Try substituting the definition of $g$ into the limit expression and observe that it factorizes nicely.

Comment: Do you have a definite answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix $h$. Let $\alpha=f(z+h)$ and  $\beta=f(z)$, note that
$$
\alpha\overline{\alpha}-\alpha\overline{\beta} - \beta \overline{\alpha}+\beta\overline{\beta}=(\alpha-\beta)(\overline{\alpha-\beta})
$$
So your limit is
$$
\lim_{h\to 0} \left[\frac{f(z+h)-f(z)}{h}\right]\overline{\left[\frac{f(z+h)-f(z)}{h}\right]} = f'(z) \: \overline{f'(z)}
$$

Comment: Thank you so much, just wonder if I am dealing with $g = \frac{1-f(z)\overline{f(w)}}{1-z\bar w}$, or more genearally some sort of rational functions of $f$ and $\bar f$, will it have the same good property?

Comment: Almost definitely (except probably for isolated cases) the general case fails. That is too good to be true.

Comment: Then it will not be true for $g = \frac{1-f(z)\overline{f(w)}}{1-z\bar w}$? Sorry for keeping bothering you, it is fine if you do not want to carry on with this.

Comment: I don't know, it shouldn't work but I don't know for sure (honestly too much of a burden to check it). If you want a fast check, you can take test functions (say polynomial), write a program with mathematica and check it.